# Function not being called specified number of times

Tags: .net, f#

```fs
open System

let repeat action count =
    for i in 1..count do
        action

let print =
    printfn "Test"

repeat print 10
```

Results in "Test" being printed only once. How should it be written to print 10 times? If the 10 is currently unused why are there no warnings?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're not defining `print` as a function but a constant value.

Functions should take at least one `unit` parameter:

```
open System

let repeat action count =
    for i in 1..count do
        action ()

let print () =
    printfn "Test"

repeat print 10
```

In your original code, the side-effect of printing happens only once, at the definition of `print`.

And there are no warnings as `print` it is used, but its value is `()`, which is the value returned by the `printfn "test"` function call.

Answer (score 3):

```
let print =
    printfn "Test"
```

This is a binding. It means that variable print is assigned to result of execution of `printfn "Test"`. Result of execution of `printfnt "Test"` is a unit `()`, which leads to following situation: `print` equals `unit`

In your loop you just return unit with each iteration, without actually calling anything.

To get desired results you need to change binding into a function:

```
open System

let repeat action count =
    for i in 1..count do
        action()

let print() =
    printfn "Test"

repeat print 10
```